# php mail and how to embed image in mail function

Tags: php, email

I Want to send mail in well-formatted HTML, I have following code.

```
$to = abc@gmail.com;
$subject = "New good bye profile claim request";
$from = " xyz@gmail.com";
$headers  = 'MIME-Version: 1.0' . "\r\n";
$headers .= 'Content-type: text/html; charset=iso-8859-1' . "\r\n";
$headers = "From: $from";
$message = '<html><body>';
$message .= '<h1 style="color:#f40;">Hi Jane!</h1>';
$message .= '<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">Will you marry me?</p>';
$message .= '</body></html>';
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

But its send mail like this.

```
<html>
<body>
<h1 style="color:#f40;">Hi Jane!</h1>
<p style="color:#080;font-size:18px;">Will you marry me?</p>
</body>
</html>
```

And I also want to send the image.

Comment: Try charset to be UTF8

Comment: And embed the image with <img> tag

Comment: And I have read somewhere that there are settings in php.ini regarding mail configuration

Answer (score 0):

You must send it as `text/html`. So you first have to extend your headers like this:

```
$header = "From: $from\nMIME-Version: 1.0\nContent-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8\n";
```

Then you must update your mail content replacing `\n` or linebreaks with MLml tags `<br>` or even `<p>`

Then you also can include image tags having the image you want to show in the email

```
<img src="http://www.yourserver.com/images/image1.jpg">
```